Injecting additional code in the `console_scripts` executable stub
Let's say I have a pip package with an executable (console_scripts in entry_points).
I can decide to install it in a random directory by using pip install --target <DIR> <PKG>.
If I am also using a Python interpreter in a non-standard location, like for example:
<MY_PYTHON>/python -m pip install --target <DIR> <PKG>

pip will be smart enough to generate a shebang that points to this location, DIR/bin/PKG will contain:
#!<MY_PYTHON>/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

Now, the question is, is there any way, through command-line options, to make pip also add something that goes like this:
import os
file_path = os.path.realpath(__file__)
sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(file_path)))

so that the console script automatically finds its main Python code?

Generally, is there any way to inject code in the small runnable script that pip produces?

Do you want to specifically only inject code with pip, or you are writing a python module and do you get some error? Do you want to specifically only inject code with pip, or you want to add a speciifc path to PYTHONPATH? Is this XY question? the console script automatically finds its main Python code? console script automtiacally finds python main code, it is given in pyproject.toml.

I can't modify (prefer not to) modify the Python module. I want to install it in a non-standard location with a non-standard interpreter and make it available as a CLI command.

@Criminal_Affair_At_SO Non-standard things aren't supported by standard tools. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5458048/how-can-i-make-a-python-script-standalone-executable-to-run-without-any-dependen My advice is to generate a standalone program. https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D+standalone

install it in a non-standard location, and add your wrapper that calls PYTHONPATH=dir ./dir/yourprog

I ended simply replacing the pip generated script. However, on Windows, pip comes with a number of pre-built exes such as W32.EXE or W64.EXE that do the same and I wonder where these come from since they seem to be comitted as binaries to git
